# How to fix DT::renderDataTable Indexation after Deletion of Row

Tags: r, shiny, dt

After I add and delete various rows in my data table, I would like the row names to still be in chronological order (1,2,3, etc.). If I use 'row.names(df1$data) <- NULL' which I have commanded out, the table is no longer editable. If I set 'rownames = NULL' inside the DT::datatable function, which I have also commanded out, the row names do not appear AND the 'NewDate' column will not update dynamically once the offset column or Date column are changed. Any suggestions?

```
x<- data.frame(FreeText=NA,Offset=NA,Date=NA,NewDate=NA)

library(shiny)
library(lubridate) #for dates 
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(title="Main Page",
          sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                  #Free Text Selection
                  textInput("dt_count", "Free Text"),
                  #Offset Days
                  numericInput("dt_off", "Offset Days", value = 4),
                  #Test Date Input
                  dateInput("dt_date", "Date Input"),
                  # Row selection
                  numericInput(inputId = "row.selection", label = "Select row to be 
deleted", min = 1, max = 100, value = ""),
                  # Add button
                  actionButton(inputId = "add.button", label = "Add", icon = 
                                   icon("plus")), 
                  # Delete button 
                  actionButton(inputId = "delete.button", label = "Delete", icon = 
                                   icon("minus"))
              ),
              mainPanel(
                  DT::dataTableOutput("newDT")
              )
          ))

# Define server 
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    #Month/Offset DT
    values <- reactiveValues()
    values$df <- x 
    
    df1 <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
    dat <-reactive(values$df) 
    
    observeEvent(input$add.button,{
        cat("addEntry\n")
        print(input$dt_count)
        print(input$dt_off)
        print(input$dt_date)
        newRow <- data.frame(input$dt_count, input$dt_off, format(input$dt_date), format(input$dt_date + input$dt_off))
        colnames(newRow)<-colnames(values$df)
        values$df <- rbind(values$df,newRow)
        print(nrow(values$df))
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$delete.button,{
        cat("deleteEntry\n")
        if(is.na(input$row.selection)){
            values$df <- values$df[-nrow(values$df), ]
        } else {
            values$df <- values$df[-input$row.selection, ]
        }
    })  
    
    observe({
        df1$data <- dat()
    })
    
    output$newDT = DT::renderDataTable({
        df1$data %>%
            DT::datatable(values$df, editable = list(target = "cell",disable = list(columns =c(4))))
        #DT::datatable(values$df, rownames = NULL, editable = list(target = "cell",disable = list(columns =c(4))))
        #row.names(df1$data) <- NULL
        #df1$data
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$newDT_cell_edit, {
        info = input$newDT_cell_edit
        str(info)
        i = info$row
        j = info$col
        k = info$value
        
        #format(input$dt_date + input$dt_off)
        df1$data[i, j] <<- (DT::coerceValue(k, df1$data[i, j]))
        df1$data[,"NewDate"] <<- df1$data[,"Offset"] + as.Date(df1$data[,"Date"])  
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not a good idea to use a reactive dataset in datatable. Here is a solution which uses a lot of JavaScript:

```r
library(shiny)
library(lubridate) #for dates 
library(DT)
library(jsonlite)


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      #Free Text Selection
      textInput("dt_count", "Free Text"),
      #Offset Days
      numericInput("dt_off", "Offset Days", value = 4, step = 1),
      #Test Date Input
      dateInput("dt_date", "Date Input"),
      # Row selection
      numericInput(
        inputId = "row_selection", 
        label = "Select row to be deleted", 
        min = 1, max = 100, step = 1, value = ""
      ),
      # Add button
      actionButton(
        inputId = "add_button", label = "Add", icon = icon("plus")
      ), 
      # Delete button 
      actionButton(
        inputId = "delete_button", label = "Delete", icon = icon("minus")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("newDT")
    )
  )
)

callback <- c(
  'var Newdate = function(date, offset){',
  '  if(date === null || offset === null){',
  '    return null;',
  '  }',
  '  date = new Date(date);',
  '  date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt(offset));',
  '  return date.toISOString().split("T")[0];',
  '};',
  '$(table.table().node()).on("blur", "input", function(e){',
  '  var index = e.originalEvent.path[1]._DT_CellIndex;',
  '  var rowIndex = index.row;',
  '  if(index.column === 2 || index.column === 3){',
  '    setTimeout(function(){',
  '      var newdate = Newdate(',
  '        table.cell({row: rowIndex, column: 3}).data(),',
  '        table.cell({row: rowIndex, column: 2}).data()',
  '      );',
  '      table.cell({row: rowIndex, column: 4}).data(newdate).draw(false);',
  '    });',
  '  }',
  '});',
  'table.on("draw.dt", function(e){',
  '  table.column(0).nodes().each(function(cell, i){', 
  '    cell.innerHTML = i + 1;',
  '  });',
  '});',
  '$("#add_button").on("click", function(){',
  '  var count = $("#dt_count").val();',
  '  var offset = $("#dt_off").val();',
  '  var date = $("#dt_date>input").val();',
  '  var newdate = Newdate(date, offset);',
  '  var newrow = [count, offset, date, newdate];',
  '  Shiny.setInputValue("newrow", JSON.stringify(newrow), {priority: "event"});',
  '  table.row.add([""].concat(newrow)).draw(false);',
  '});',
  '$("#delete_button").on("click", function(){',
  '  var index = parseInt($("#row_selection").val())',
  '  if(!isNaN(index) && index !== 0){',
  '    table.row(index-1).remove().draw(false);',
  '    Shiny.setInputValue("deletedrow", index, {priority: "event"});',
  '  }',
  '});'
)

# Define server 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  x <- data.frame(
    FreeText = NA_character_,
    Offset   = NA_integer_,
    Date     = NA_character_,
    NewDate  = NA_character_
  )

  observeEvent(input[["newrow"]], {
    x <<- rbind(x, fromJSON(input[["newrow"]], simplifyVector = FALSE))
    print(x)
  })

  observeEvent(input[["deletedrow"]], {
    x <<- x[-input[["deletedrow"]], ]
    print(x)
  })
  
  output[["newDT"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      x, 
      rownames = TRUE,
      editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = 4)),
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["newDT_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["newDT_cell_edit"]]
    x <<- editData(x, info, proxy = NULL, rownames = TRUE)
    if(info[["col"]] == 2L){
      info2 <- data.frame(
        row = info[["row"]], 
        col = 4L, 
        value = format(as.Date(input[["dt_date"]]) + info[["value"]])
      )
      x <<- editData(x, info2, proxy = NULL, rownames = TRUE)
    }else if(info[["col"]] == 3L){
      info2 <- data.frame(
        row = info[["row"]], 
        col = 4L, 
        value = as.Date(info[["value"]]) + as.integer(input[["dt_off"]])
      )
      x <<- editData(x, info2, proxy = NULL, rownames = TRUE)
    }
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you this is helpful - do you recommend another way to display reactive data if not in a data table like this? Ultimately I am looking to have a table where certain values are pulled in from a data source while others are entered in by the user. Both pulled in values and values provided by the user will be used in dynamic calculations.